# afuse with sshfs: where do fuse tuning options go?

Tags: sshfs, fuse

I'm using [afuse](https://github.com/pcarrier/afuse) to mount some remote directories via [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). This works well, but I'm interested in exploring some options like `-o kernel_cache` and `-o large_read`.

Afuse works by specifying a `mount_template`, in this case a string which contains an sshfs invocation. Now, obviously, sshfs options like `-o reconnect` or `-o transform_symlinks` go in that template, and afuse options like `-o timeout=300` go on the afuse command line.

But what about *fuse* options which can apply to both? Should these go:

- in the sshfs invocation template?
- directly to the afuse command?
- or, *both*?

Will using the options twice result in (for example) unnecessary double-buffering, or is it necessary for it to be in both places to be meaningful? (For example, large reads might need to be enabled in both places or else they're broken up.)

Answer (score 0):

If this is still useful to someone, here is the basic idea:

Create an executable script called `mount.afuse` and put it in `/usr/bin/mount.afuse`

```
su -l $( ls -dl "$2" | cut -d' ' -f3) -c "afuse -o mount_template='sshfs -o reconnect -o auto_cache -o kernel_cache %r:/ %m' -o unmount_template='fusermount -u -z %m' -o auto_unmount '$2'"
```

Include a line in your `/etc/fstab`

```
afuse# /mnt/afuse afuse auto 0 0
```

To test that everything works, you should be able to execute the `mount.afuse` script first.

Source: https://gist.github.com/Hubbitus/c40d986921cbed6a8ad585eee00a7d77